# How to replace Facebook Native Ad widget with any widget in case of error and can I preload Facebook native ad in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to show Facebook Native ads using [Facebook Audience Network](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network) in a Flutter app. In case of any error loading native ads, I can't replace 'my native ad widget' with alternative widget. Here is my code creating Native Ad widget:

```
Container(
  //height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.07),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
  child: FacebookNativeAd(
    placementId: "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID",
    adType: Platform.isAndroid ? NativeAdType.NATIVE_AD : NativeAdType.NATIVE_AD_VERTICAL,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white12,
    titleColor: Colors.white,
    descriptionColor: Colors.white,
    buttonColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    buttonTitleColor: Colors.white,
    buttonBorderColor: Colors.white,
    listener: (result, value) {
      print("FB Native Ad: $result --> $value");
      if(value["invalidated"]) {
        print("Sth went wrong...Replace ad widget witt sth else...");
        return Text("Error... There is a problem with Facebook Native ad");
      }
    },
    keepExpandedWhileLoading: true,
    expandAnimationDuraion: 1000,
  ),
)
```

I'm trying to handle this in `listener: (result, value){ //handle error }`; I can read the `print('Sth went wrong...')` message in debug console, but the ad widget wasn't replaced with `Text('Error...')`. So how to replace my native ad widget with another widget in case of any error loading native ads?
Secondly is there any way to preload(e.g. in `initState()`) Facebook native ad? Thank you.